# Django DateTimeWidget ValidationError with localization

Tags: python, django, datetime-format

I want to use django-datetime-widget in Polish language. But following instruction from [project's github](https://github.com/asaglimbeni/django-datetime-widget#installation) give me error. My situation is:

form:

```
class add_test_form(forms.Form):
    test_date_finish = forms.DateTimeField(label="Termin zakonczenia testu", widget=DateTimeWidget(usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3), localize=True)
```

view:

```
test = Test(test_date_start = request.POST['test_date_start'])
test.save()
```

model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
test_date_finish = models.DateTimeField()
```

settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl-pl'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

I got ValidationError in Polish which translates into:

```
[...] value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[." "uuuuuu]][TZ] format.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date-time format isn't right, you should set it. This code in the project's docs may help you with that. Probably you should put this on your settings.py and change the `format` part according to your datetime format.

```
dateTimeOptions = {
'format': 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii P',
'autoclose': True,
'showMeridian' : True
}
widgets = {
    #NOT Use localization and set a default format
    'datetime': DateTimeWidget(options = dateTimeOptions)
    }
```

Comment: I tired many formats but no luck so far. I seems to me like Django's model object cannot accept datetime format like that. My local format is `dd.mm.yyyy HH:ii:ss` but model accepts mentioned before `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]`.

Comment: You may try to format your date in your view before sending it to database. Splitting and adding should be proper to do that.